# Render a page with express, then print it with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, puppeteer

I want to send the form infos to the same url, get the documents that match the infos on the url, render the page with the documents and then print that page with puppeteer in a pdf format (every document will become a page and then a pdf document at the end).
this is the code I am using:

the route that receives the request in documentRoutes:

```
router.use(
  '/:document',
  documentController.getDocument,
  documentController.printDocument
);
```

the middlewares:

getDocument:

```
exports.getDocument = async (req, res, next) => {
  const course = req.params.document.split('-')[0];
  const document = req.params.document.split('-')[1];
  
  
  const documents = await Document.find({ CODE: course });
  res.status(200).render(`${document}`, {
  title: document,
  documents,
});

next();
};
```

printDocument:

```
exports.printDocument = async (req, res, next) => {
  const url = req.params.document;

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',
  });
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(`http://localhost:3000/${url}`);

  await page.pdf({
    path: path.join(appRoot.path, 'downloads/certificate.pdf'),
    format: 'A4',
    margin: {
    top: '1cm',
    left: '1cm',
    right: '1cm',
    bottom: '1cm',
   },
 });

  await browser.close();
  console.log('pdf generated successfully');
  await browser.close();
  next();
};
```

error message:
Error Unexpected extraInfo events for request 70460993C8EB5E671E4D72B16003040A

Comment: the localhost:3000/:document url request comes like this: /:course-document, then I split it to extract the course and it's corresponding document to print.